# Is there an alternative CSS technique I can use to workaround Safari's incomplete support for flex-grow?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm making an "accordion" widget which can contain any number of child items. When a child item is closed, it shrinks to the height of its header. When it's open, it distributes its height to be the same as the other open siblings around it. I'm sure you've seen the type of thing before - click the codepen below if this doesn't make sense.

This seemed like a good candidate for flexbox (though I'm not an expert). I came up with this which uses flex-grow and works exactly as I want in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari. Safari seems to not expand the child items if the vertical space is already taken - so after you open one item, you can't easily open a second.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>foo</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>foo</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>foo</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>foo</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  .item
    // this is the closed height
    flex-basis: 20px
    flex-grow: 0
    transition: flex-grow .3s ease-out
    &.open
      flex-grow: 1
```

https://codepen.io/suchesuch/pen/EEazdV

Does anyone know a way I can work around this or an alternative CSS property I can modify to achieve the same result?

To be clear, I'm looking for an (ideally elegant but doesn't have to be) CSS solution here. I don't want to calculate heights in JS as that will get ugly in the rest of the code base.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Aside from the transition, it's working for me on Safari 11.0.3

Comment: Really?! If you open one box, can you then open a second?

Comment: I can't test safari. But, have you tried display: grid ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use -webkit prefix

```
.flex-item {
  -webkit-flex-grow: ; /* Safari */
  flex-grow:         ;
}
```

Here is a good description for flex.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties#flex-grow

From your codepen

```
// the main workings
.wrapper
  display: flex
  display: -webkit-flex
  flex-direction: column
  -webkit-flex-direction: column
  .item
    // this is the closed height
    flex-basis: 20px
    -webkit-flex-basis: 20px
    flex-grow: 0
    // safari specific
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0
    transition: flex-grow .3s ease-out
    &.open
      flex-grow: 1
      -webkit-flex-grow: 1

// boring stuff for display etc
.wrapper
  height: 300px
  width: 100px
  border: 1px solid black
  .item
    position: relative
    h3
      height: 20px
      padding: 0
      margin: 0
      background: lightgreen
      cursor: pointer
    &.open h3
      background: lightblue
    p
      position: absolute
      top: 20px
      left: 0
      right: 0
      bottom: 0
      background: yellow
      margin: 0
      padding: 0
      overflow: hidden
```

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have said. The CSS pre-processor I'm using is adding the required vendor prefixes.

Comment: hmm.... or is it? I've edited the codepen to add that in. It doesn't fix the issue either way. Thanks though.

Comment: Every flex css has a safari comaptibile webkit tag. Here what I mean.
// the main workings
.wrapper
  display: flex
  display: -webkit-flex
  flex-direction: column
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  .item
    // this is the closed height
    flex-basis: 20px
    -webkit-flex-basis: 20px
    flex-grow: 0
    // safari specific
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0
    transition: flex-grow .3s ease-out
    &.open
      flex-grow: 1
      -webkit-flex-grow: 1